# How to set trackpoint speed for Thinkpad?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, thinkpad, trackpoint

First of all I have read a lot of thread about this on the Internet, but none of them seems to work for me. I got this set command that I got from another user and that seems to be the only thing that had worked for me. I don't know how to set this in Ubuntu because normally I would have this be executed in `~/.xinitrc`.

```
#get the device ID for the trackpad.
ibm_trackpad_id=$(xinput | grep 'TPPS' | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -f1)

echo $ibm_trackpad_id > ~/temp/ibm_trackpad_id
#set desired params for trackpoint
sleep 2; xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 1

sleep 2; xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 2

sleep 2; xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 200

sleep 2; xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 6 7 4 5

sleep 2; xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 0.15
```

Answer (score 0):

create a file called .xessionrc and put these command into it:

```
#get the device ID for the trackpad. We know it contains the string "TPPS"
ibm_trackpad_id=$(xinput | grep 'TPPS' | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -f1)
echo $ibm_trackpad_id > ~/temp/ibm_trackpad_id

#set desired params for trackpoint
xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 1
xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 2
xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 200
xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 7 6 5 4
xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 0.10
```